# CodeIgniter - Why does encrypting with the same key produce different results?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption, cryptography

I use codeigniter a lot, however I am not really understanding why when I use the encryption library in version 3 the encryption string never comes out the same, even using the same salt/key.

So I have stored a user password as an encrypted string, which uses their own key to encrypt. The key is stored in the database. But when they come to login, and i want to encrypt the entered password to check the strings match, they never do match!

It seems the library always spits out different encrypted strings, no matter if the key is the same or not, how is this going to be useful if I can't match the stored encrypted password to the password they enter at login?

For example, password is 12456 with key a0956f251b9d957071005a2d11e4630a

SAVED PASSWORD IS: 0e6effa48949d6bf19e84530bc86e9a1407086b3b88fc368b6f8b7b53304b313eeebdb695c9cca10b3e7072f608bf4137e7fcc7d24fed54df2b6dcba3f94dcb6Tm05Qmay9G8JuUXps6UstWebmBmJ71BcIPgrW78OvSY=

PASSWORD GENERATED FROM USER LOGIN

6b893dac92155bc663b126b805c7189214ac4667b226f0c6fc22cf0c6bcca5e897c49961e8852ade1c3e85cbecab89df76ea7891727af6bf0bcc232b75d0d441LLUMZgOy4zLwAypuVQuK0lKTXrlXYptKpVdByytH2D8=

935c8f564c4a5ecb53510faa835eca8622069c34d534df6b9c2ea52de2d9bea5976128f6ff83a572ac677be4ebd690bc18e488518c2eed8b1b40a16c9e61d6b2hbKJ6B1VDuLPCXBeDDFzvrlSBIYCtN19M6dQGZRCvUE=

b8e020c7c10d564cfc3a9cc4d50b85ea3422422b73a2dd79930ead1fb601493279ba97645584d6dfa188e62f5eba5dc66d0dafdb7a82c08bf847bc84fc0718daSOVRrDlFmVMB/12ok9kR68ekXJcJvw0yfo/cnU9ojtI=

see they are different every time I try to encrypt the user input? It's not making any sense.

Likewise, if I try to decode the password in the database, with the same key it was encrypted with, I get nothing back, no decrypted password.

So, does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: I would look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php for creating passwords.

Answer (score 4):

Randomized encryption is a security property necessary to achieve semantic security. If the encryption would not be randomized then an attacker might detect whether (prefixes of) messages were previously sent only by observing the ciphertexts. You generally don't want the attacker to know anything about the plaintexts except the length.

An encryption function has always a corresponding decryption function. It seems that you're only using one way of the two functions. You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being [PBKDF2](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library), bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just found the issue, rather than encrypting again, i decrypt the saved password and check that way. Anyway, the main problem turned out that i was generating a key again by mistake and using that rather than the stored key...like a dumb ass!

Comment: As I said, if you're handling passwords, then you don't want to make them decryptable. Databases get lost all the time and then you're basically giving a clear text (decryption key is close to the data) database to an attacker that can try to use those passwords on other sites.

Comment: Padding can help by obscuring the length of a message if that is important.

Answer (score 2):

Codigniter documentation:

> DO NOT use this or any other encryption library for user password
>   storage! Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that via
>   PHP’s own Password Hashing extension.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html

Fully explained here:

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score -3):

Try the md5 encryption its good and best till now.
In controller before send password like this:

```
md5($this->input->post('password));
```

or use `hash()` or `SHA256/SHA512` they do it well.

It will do the trick.

Enjoy!

Comment: MD5 is very unsecure now better to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: i wouldn't use md5, that's an old and insecure method of doing it. I actually just found the issue, rather than encrypting again, i decrypt the saved password and check that way. Anyway, the main problem turned out that i was generating a key again by mistake and using that rather than the stored key...like a dumb ass!

Comment: Then use hash() or SHA256/SHA512. they do it well. After submitting are you redirecting page to anywhere else because reloading page sometimes create new data.

Comment: MD5, indeed and cryptographic function, is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function, there is no reversing operation.

Comment: and how about mcrypt_encrypt(). this will be better i think. i just did study on it.

Comment: "Try the md5 encryption" [MD5 is not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

"and how about mcrypt_encrypt()" [If you're typing the word MCRYPT into your PHP code, you're doing it wrong!](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)